# Как можно посмотреть папку установленного приложения в AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть приложение которое делает фото сохраняет его во внутреннее хранилище
Как можно добраться до этого файла где его искать на моем планшете его не видно нигде в /data
В AndroidStudio как-то можно посмотреть папку приложения которое установлено на эмуляторе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tools → Android → Android Device Monitor → File Explorer